# Adapting the width of the KineticJs canvas on mobile window resize event

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I'm trying to adapt the width of my Kinetic.Stage to the 100%. As Kinetic.Stage doesn't let me put that value (100%) I had to put the window.innerWidth value.

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: window.innerWidth - 20, 
    height: 200
});
```

The problem is it doesn't change when resized:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    stage.setWidth(window.content.innerWidth );  
}
```

I'm developing a mobile app and I really need to change the width when the phone is rotated.

You can see a working demo here, and you'll see there is no width adaptation when window is resized: http://jsfiddle.net/gal007/xzwohvy9/14/

Can you help me, please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What is `window.content` in your code?

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    stage.setWidth(window.innerWidth);  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xzwohvy9/15/

Comment: It doesn't work dynamically. Try to resize  the window: the yellow area has the initial size. window.content.document is the same as just document

Comment: Maybe you need to resize `Rect`, not the `Stage`? Or both.